# TeXstudio no longer loads after Windows 10 update

Tags: texlive, texstudio, windows

After my previous laptop (running Windows 8.1) broke down, I've had to buy a new one (running Windows 10). I installed TeXLive and TeXstudio, which was also my setup on the previous machine. For a few days it ran okay. Then yesterday evening I shut down the computer for a Windows 10 update. After booting it back up this morning TeXstudio would no longer load. When I start it up, the splash screen shows as it always does and then it just shows a white window with "TeXstudio (not responding)" at the top and the cursor turns into the blue "loading" ring.

I've tried restarting the laptop and I've tried starting it by opening a random TeX file I have saved on my laptop, in case there was an issue with the file I had been working on yesterday (which doesn't seem possible, because I think I compiled it just fine before I shut down the computer yesterday). Apart from reinstalling TeXstudio, which I am reluctant to do, I am out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** reinstalling works, if you make sure to delete the `texstudio` folder in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\` after uninstalling TeXstudio. I also reverted all but one (security) update that Windows 10 had performed before doing this, but I cannot be sure the problem wouldn't have been fixed without deleting those updates.

---

**More details:** the folder in question is where the configuration settings are stored (`texstudio.ini`) as well as information about the state of the program at the end of the last session (`lastSession.txss`). Presumably one of these two files was causing the issue and perhaps just deleting them would have worked - I don't know how TeXstudio responds if it cannot find these files, though I assume it will just generate new (default) ones.

In any case, it's still unclear to me why precisely the problem occurred, but given the fact that the Windows 10 updates were literally the only activity on my laptop between TeXstudio working and no longer working, I believe they were at least related to, if not the root of, the problem.